# Update time part only of Date field

Tags: oracle

I have a table with some columns of `Date` datatype. I need to keep the `Date` part as it is, but I need to format the `time` part to 00:00:00 for all of them.
For example:

```
09-FEB-14 09:00:00
10-MAR-12 12:00:00
```

I need to update them to:

```
09-FEB-14 00:00:00
10-MAR-12 00:00:00
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you appear to want to truncate the time part back to midnight then you can just use the `TRUNC` function:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date_column = TRUNC( date_column )
```

If, instead, you want to set them to a specific time then you can use `TRUNC` and add an `INTERVAL` literal:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date_column = TRUNC( date_column ) + INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND;
```

If you want to take an hour off the time then you can subtract an `INTERVAL` literal:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date_column = date_column - INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
```

or subtract a fraction of a day:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date_column = date_column - 1/24;
```